# Error in deploying odoo. Cannot install dependencies see pip log

Tags: odoo

I downloaded the zip of the source code from here.

https://github.com/odoo/odoo

and run it (after installing dependencies) locally using this command

```
python3 odoo-bin -w odoo -r odoo --addons-path=addons --db-filter=.*
```

and it was working fine.

Then I push the code in the repository which was linked with `odoo.sh` but build failed and error occurred which says could not install dependencies see pip log.

[image]

**PIP Log:**

[image]

I expect it should be deployed on cloud as its running locally also the code that I pushed was the their source code.

Can anyone tell me How to fix this issue?

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This seems might be any addons or lib issue.

Comment: It looks that you are pushing the entire community version addons to odoo.sh. You only need to push your customized and/or community addons folder, not the ones from Odoo.

Comment: @mingtwo_h9, You are right. I have already identified and fixed this issue, post this comment as answer so that I can up-vote and accept it. Thanks for your response.